# Would 1 W of electrical power kill you?

Tags: power, current, safety

If we have a wire, which is transporting 1 μA of current at 1 MV, the electrical power will be 1 W. If I touch the wire without properly insulating myself, will it kill me?

I read all the answer and comments. Many wanted a clarification whether the current happens to be 1 μA or 1 μA is the current limit. So, 1 μA is the actual current limit. The current won't go above 1 μA.

Comment: Draw the circuit diagram and compute how much current is likely to pass through the body in your scenario. You can do some googling and check what current values are lethal. Typical body electrical resistance values also you will need to find out to compute the current.     Note that power of 1W is dissipated in the load. The 1uA current is going into the load. The current passing through the body will not be 1uA. You'll have to compute it

Comment: This critically depends on the source impedance of whatever is applying the 1 MV to the line. It doesn't depend at all on the current through the line before you touch it.

Comment: Apparently 0.2V at the right time in the heart cycle can stop it - if "right" is the correct term :)

Comment: Ignoring the 1 MV and just looking at 1 W, at 1.5 kohm for the human body model, 1 W gives about 26 mA. Certainly painful but not immediately deadly.  Don’t bet your life on it though as your mileage may vary! Please clarify if it’s 1 MV with 1 uA current limit or 1 MV and the current just happens to be 1 uA.

Comment: @winny "don't bet your life on it as your _resistance_ may vary". :-)

Comment: I bet the wire doesn't have zero capacitance to ground. Think energy.

Comment: In this scenario why would current pass through your body anyway? Where is the ground? Birds sit down on high voltage lines all the time...

Answer (score 10):

Let's see:

> If we have a wire, which is transporting 1 μA of current at 1 MV

This means that there's a load of 1 TOhm (teraohm) at the end of the transmission line that draws 1 uA from 1 MV source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXHXC4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

> If I touch the wire without properly insulating myself

So I'm assuming that the source and your body share the same reference (ground):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKTdwg.png)</sup>

The resistance from touch point to ground is taken as 25 kOhm but this can vary with several conditions such as body temperature, environment, whether the body is wet or not, etc.

In this case, one of the following can happen:

1. If the source is not current-limited then you'll turn into smoke in a fraction of a second. In fact, you don't have to touch the line because even being in close proximity without touching will be enough to put you in an eternal sleep.
2. If the source is current-limited (1 uA) then the voltage across you (or your touch point: tongue, finger, foot, nose, etc) will be a few volts. And it won't kill you. Up to 120 VDC or 50 Vac is safe to touch. You may feel something (e.g. tickling) though, depending on some conditions.
3. If the source is power-limited (1 W) then the current flowing through your body will be something around 6 mA (I = sqrt(P/R) = sqrt(1/25k)). Note that if the body resistance is lower (quite possible) the current will be higher. IEC-60479-1 defines four zones for current and duration to explain the effects to body. So the current (magnitude) drops into AC-2 and AC-3 regions (depending on the duration) which mean non-lethal effects.
   [image]

NOTE: Any possible drops on the transmission line are ignored.

Comment: I would emphasize that when the source is not current limited, one turns to smoke _without even touching the wire_. Getting close will be enough.

Comment: In your scenario 3 the voltage across the human body would be 150V. I seem to recall the human body experiences some kind of dielectric breakdown and its resistance decreases; since we assume constant power in this scenario, voltage goes down and current goes up. This is probably borderline as to whether it can kill you or not.

Comment: @PMF that's a good point. I should add it to my answer.

Comment: @user253751 if you have a reference that explains the phenomenon I'm happy to add it into my answer.

Comment: @RohatKılıç no specific reference but notice that your analysis says that touching 110V mains can't cause death, which we know is false

Comment: @RohatKılıç : do you have a source for the diagram at the end? The version without the blue lines is well known, but it's the first time I see the DC version. So if you have a "serious" source baking it, I would be very interestde. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: There's one more gotcha worth pointing out: parasitic capacitance charged to 1MV can be dangerous. Even if the source is limited to 1uA, the parasitic capacitance isn't and will happily discharge at whatever current can flow through the body.  1pF charged to 1MV has the same energy as 100uF charged to 100V - 0.5J. It will be a solid jolt. It is a ~3 orders of magnitude lower energy than that required for defibrillation, but still not benign.

Comment: You can determine your own threshold of sensation using a TENS unit. For myself, I can begin to feel a tingle at about 5 mA, and I usually use 15-25 mA for therapeutic stimulation. This is a fairly high voltage (300-500V) current controlled source, and uses conductive pads on the skin for better conductivity and reduction of pain that would occur with a smaller area. It's related to watts per square centimeter.

Comment: @Sandro IEC 60479-1 and -2 defines separate graphs for AC and [DC](https://i.imgur.com/sKbmsqx.png). The one above is simply a combination of both.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 2):

Going back to Ohm’s law your load has a resistance of:

R = 10^6 V/ 10^-6 A = 10^12 ohms

However, if you insert yourself into the circuit this would load would effectively act as an open circuit and you would be getting the full 1 MV. Given human resistance is on the scale of 10^3 - 10^4 ohms you would have a current of 100 - 1000 amps going through you.

Answer (score 1):

At 1MV, your goal of "properly insulating [your]self" would become quite vain and meaningless. At such high voltages, all the materials we commonly regard as insulators become quite good conductors, even the air. And you wouldn't even have to touch the wire, the spark would be able to jump through around 0.33 meters through air and zap you. The amount of current that would pass through you would depend on the properties of the source, though, such as its internal resistance. Resistance of human body becomes much lower once the current breaks through skin, so depending on how you would place the electrodes, it can definitely be fatal. If a direct connection through heart is created, even as little as 0.01 mA can be lethal ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=FpSH-VM5TYkC&pg=PA122&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

If we assume source's power limit as 1 W, then it could still be lethal. Heart on itself has resistance of a few ohms. Extreme case, if you happen to touch the wire with your bare heart (for example, while laying on the surgical bed and having some cardiovascular upgrades installed in you), then it's lights out because the current going through the heart is around 300 to 700 mA. Then, as we move further away from the theoretical worst case scenario, there is still a non-negligible danger zone until you have enough meat in the way to go below around 0.01 mA going through the heart.

By the way, if a 1.000.000 V source pushes just 1 μA of current through a wire, then the wire's resistance is 10<sup>12</sup> Ω. In most common applications, that's regarded as an insulator. Assuming that the resistance isn't coming from the source's internal structure, the wire must be made out of wood or glass.

Answer (score 1):

> If I touch the wire without properly insulating myself, will it kill
> me?

No, because high voltages tend to move along the skin of a human and you would need a lot more current. The university of ohio [says 200mA is necessary](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/physics/p616/safety/fatal_current.html)

Comment: High voltages tend to move along the skin? I've heard of skin effect with high frequencies, but how would absolute voltage change much here? Do you have some references for that? If that's a thing, then I'd surely like to learn about it.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking of high frequency high voltage. LIke as in telsa coil, I've seen a case where someone lit a lightbulb while standing on a tesla coil, I was trying to find that image...

Comment: The university of Ohio link also says that breathing will stop at 75 mA. I suggest that lack of breathing might also be fatal if there is no intervention.

Comment: That link does not look reputable, particularly given that it appears to be sourced from an out-of-business electrical firm. Merely being hosted on a university website does not make a source reputable.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember that right, atrial fibrillating currents are in the order of 50 mA, then 1 uA is safe - and I'd say imperceptible, but I don't have memories of figures on perception.
Note also that a 1 uA of current can charge a storage device, and build up enough charge to be lethal if coming from a 1 MV generator.

1W over 50 mA would need 20V, which is again safe, as at that voltage you wouldn't be able to let it flow through the human body. In the worst case of 20V AC (say at 50 Hz) you could probably have a current flow in the body of around 6 mA, estimating a 3 kOhm reactance.

Comment: IIRC around 100 uA -ish (that's microAmpers) you barely start to percieve the current like a tingeling at your fingertip.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the output impedance of the 1MV source. In other words, what limits the output current?

If it can only source 1uA you would probably not even feel it. I have discharged an estimated 30kV spark into my eyeball and felt very little (static charged balloon).

On the other hand, if it can source 1000A you would disappear in a ball of fire